# how can I run my exe files using batch script depending upon the edition of windows

Tags: windows, batch

I have list of few exe files  that works according to windows edition for ex.  there are different files for windows 10 pro , windows 10 home , windows 7 professional ,windows 7 enterprises and so on .

here I want to create a batch file  which will detect the windows edition and according to that windows edition my batch file will install the exe file.
i can get the windows edition details using
**wmic os get caption**
*and*
**FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3,4,5" %%i IN (`REG query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName`) DO echo %%i %%j %%k**

But I do not know how to put if condition on these commands so that I could run exe file according to windows edition

Comment: Maybe instead of `DO echo %%i %%j %%k` you use `DO set "var=%%i %%j %%k"` and then based on that `%var%` value you do conditional things with [`IF`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) statements.

Comment: Thank Pimp Juice IT       it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

May you can try:

1. Remove `usebackq`:

   `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3,4,5"`
2. Add Apostrophes in `('command loop')`:

   `('REG query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName')`

   - In command line:

   ```
   FOR /F tokens^=3-5 %i IN ('REG query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName') DO echo %i %j %k
   ```

   - In bat file:

   ```
   FOR /F tokens^=3-5 %%i IN ('REG query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName') DO echo\ %%i %%j %%k
   ```